# Rename/recode variable value in R based on condition using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, recode, mutate

I have a dataset `dataExtended` with variable `CountryOther` and `n` which is a count of wines in that particular country. `CountryOther` is character type and `n` is integer. What I want to do, is to rename values in `CountryOther` to *Other* in case the `n <=20`. I would like to do it with dyplr package and I am not sure how to do it and if to use only `mutate` or `mutate_at`.

As long as I wasn't able to do wrote the condition as stated above, I tried to do it manually as follows but it didn't work:

```
dataExtended$CountryOther <- dataExtended$Country
dataExtended %>% 
  mutate(CountryOther = recode(CountryOther,
                               China = "Other", 
                               Mexico = "Other", 
                               Slovakia = "Other",
                               Bulgaria = "Other", 
                               Canada = "Other", 
                               Croatia = "Other", 
                               Uruguay = "Other", 
                               Georgia = "Other", 
                               Turkey = "Other", 
                               Moldova = "Other", 
                               Slovenia = "Other", 
                               Hungary = "Other", 
                               Switzerland = "Other", 
                               Greece = "Other", 
                               Israel = "Other", 
                               Lebanon= "Other"))
```

Comment: An easy way is with `forcats` `?fct_lump`

Comment: (1) You could try `dataExtended %>% mutate(CountryOther = ifelse(n <= 2, "Other", CountryOther))`, (2) Please take a look at [How to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello @MartinGal I wasn't successful. Here is dataset Red.csv  from Kaggle t.ly/-UPAq

#Create new dataframe
`wineCount <- data %>% count(Country)`
#Join the tables to create an extended dataset
`dataExtended <- inner_join(wineCount, data, by = "Country")`
# Create new variable CountryOther
`dataExtended$CountryOther <- dataExtended$Country`
# Rename variable n to WineCount => NOT WORKING
`rename(dataExtended, WineCount=n)`
# Replace name of the country to Other if n or WineCount is <=20 => NOT WORKING
`dataExtended %>% mutate(CountryOther = if_else(n<=20, "Other", CountryOther))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Red.csv` from your link imported with `readr::read_csv()` creates a `data.frame` / `tibble`

```r
#> data
# A tibble: 8,666 × 8
   Name                               Country     Region       Winery                   Rating NumberOf…¹ Price Year 
   <chr>                              <chr>       <chr>        <chr>                     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1 Pomerol 2011                       France      Pomerol      Château La Providence       4.2        100 95    2011 
 2 Lirac 2017                         France      Lirac        Château Mont-Redon          4.3        100 15.5  2017 
 3 Erta e China Rosso di Toscana 2015 Italy       Toscana      Renzo Masi                  3.9        100  7.45 2015 
 4 Bardolino 2019                     Italy       Bardolino    Cavalchina                  3.5        100  8.72 2019 
 5 Ried Scheibner Pinot Noir 2016     Austria     Carnuntum    Markowitsch                 3.9        100 29.2  2016 
 6 Gigondas (Nobles Terrasses) 2017   France      Gigondas     Vieux Clocher               3.7        100 19.9  2017 
 7 Marion's Vineyard Pinot Noir 2016  New Zealand Wairarapa    Schubert                    4          100 43.9  2016 
 8 Red Blend 2014                     Chile       Itata Valley Viña La Causa               3.9        100 17.5  2014 
 9 Chianti 2015                       Italy       Chianti      Castello Montaùto           3.6        100 10.8  2015 
10 Tradition 2014                     France      Minervois    Domaine des Aires Hautes    3.5        100  6.9  2014 
# … with 8,656 more rows, and abbreviated variable name ¹​NumberOfRatings
```

Now with `dplyr`s help

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  add_count(Country, name = "WineCount") %>% 
  mutate(CountryOther = ifelse(WineCount <= 20, "Other", Country))
```

we get

```r
# A tibble: 8,666 × 10
   Name                               Country     Region       Winery      Rating Numbe…¹ Price Year  WineC…² Count…³
   <chr>                              <chr>       <chr>        <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int> <chr>  
 1 Pomerol 2011                       France      Pomerol      Château La…    4.2     100 95    2011     2256 France 
 2 Lirac 2017                         France      Lirac        Château Mo…    4.3     100 15.5  2017     2256 France 
 3 Erta e China Rosso di Toscana 2015 Italy       Toscana      Renzo Masi     3.9     100  7.45 2015     2650 Italy  
 4 Bardolino 2019                     Italy       Bardolino    Cavalchina     3.5     100  8.72 2019     2650 Italy  
 5 Ried Scheibner Pinot Noir 2016     Austria     Carnuntum    Markowitsch    3.9     100 29.2  2016      220 Austria
 6 Gigondas (Nobles Terrasses) 2017   France      Gigondas     Vieux Cloc…    3.7     100 19.9  2017     2256 France 
 7 Marion's Vineyard Pinot Noir 2016  New Zealand Wairarapa    Schubert       4       100 43.9  2016       63 New Ze…
 8 Red Blend 2014                     Chile       Itata Valley Viña La Ca…    3.9     100 17.5  2014      326 Chile  
 9 Chianti 2015                       Italy       Chianti      Castello M…    3.6     100 10.8  2015     2650 Italy  
10 Tradition 2014                     France      Minervois    Domaine de…    3.5     100  6.9  2014     2256 France
# … with 8,656 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​NumberOfRatings, ²​WineCount, ³​CountryOther
```

We can filter for `WineCount <= 30`:

```r
# A tibble: 125 × 10
   Name                                  Country     Region         Winery Rating Numbe…¹ Price Year  WineC…² Count…³
   <chr>                                 <chr>       <chr>          <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int> <chr>  
 1 Steiner 2013                          Hungary     Sopron         Wenin…    3.7     100 24.5  2013        9 Other  
 2 Viile Metamorfosis Merlot 2015        Romania     Dealu Mare     Vitis…    3.5     102  7.5  2015       23 Romania
 3 Halkidiki Limnio - Merlot 2013        Greece      Chalkidiki     Tsant…    3.2     105 12.5  2013       13 Other  
 4 Cabernet Sauvignon 2013               Mexico      Valle de Guad… L. A.…    3.4    1066  8.65 2013        1 Other  
 5 Driopi Classic Agiorgitiko Nemea 2017 Greece      Nemea          Κτημα…    3.7     107 11.5  2017       13 Other  
 6 Malbec de Purcari 2018                Moldova     South Eastern  Châte…    4.1     107 12.0  2018        8 Other  
 7 Cabernet Sauvignon de Purcari 2017    Moldova     South Eastern  Châte…    4.1    1082 13.0  2017        8 Other  
 8 Cabernet Sauvignon 2016               Romania     Samburesti     Caste…    3.3     112  7.9  2016       23 Romania
 9 Aigle Les Murailles Rouge 2015        Switzerland Aigle          Henri…    3.7     112 23.2  2015       12 Other  
10 Γουμένισσα (Goumenissa) 2015          Greece      Goumenissa     Chatz…    3.7     115 20    2015       13 Other
```

to check the desired output: There are several rows filled with `"Other"` in column `CountryOther`.

Answer (score 1):

in the end I created this code which works:

```
#New table with wine count
wineCount <- data %>% count(Country)
#Joining two tables together
dataExtended <- inner_join(wineCount, data, by = "Country")
# Creating new variable CountryOther
dataExtended$CountryOther <- dataExtended$Country
# Renaming count from n to WineCount
dataExtended <- rename(dataExtended, WineCount = n)
# Replacement of countries with WineCount<=20 to Other
dataExtended <- dataExtended %>% 
  mutate(CountryOther = ifelse(WineCount<=20, "Other", CountryOther))
# Final check
unique(dataExtended$CountryOther)
```

The problem was I needed to store changes into the dataframe, which I didn't do before (as you can see in my last comment):

```
dataExtended <- rename(dataExtended, WineCount = n)
```

and

```
dataExtended <- dataExtended %>% 
  mutate(CountryOther = ifelse(WineCount<=20, "Other", CountryOther))
```

I also tested your code and it works as well and additionally it looks neater. So thank you very much for your help.